# C functions to create dynamic array of structs

Tags: c, struct, indexing, dynamic-allocation

can someone help with this piece of code? I leaved out check of allocations to keep it brief.

```
typedef struct {
  int x;
  int y;
} MYSTRUCT;

void init(MYSTRUCT **p_point);
void plusOne(MYSTRUCT **p_point, int *p_size);

int main()
{
  MYSTRUCT *point;
  int size = 1;

  init(&point);

  plusOne(&point, &size);
  plusOne(&point, &size);

  point[1]->x = 47;  //  this was the problem
  point[1].x = 47;   //  this is solution    

  return 0;
}

void init(MYSTRUCT **p_point)
{
  *p_point = (MYSTRUCT *) malloc( sizeof(MYSTRUCT) );
}

void plusOne(MYSTRUCT **p_point, int *p_size) 
{
  (*p_size)++;

  *p_point = realloc(*p_point, *p_size * sizeof(MYSTRUCT) ); // also calling to the function is fixed
}
```

I don't understand why index notation doesn't work after calling to functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are not multiplying the `p_size` by `sizeof(MYSTRUCT)` in the call of `realloc`, and not assigning the results back to `p_point`:

```
*p_point = realloc(*p_point, *p_size * sizeof(MYSTRUCT));
```

Notes:

- You do not need to cast the result of `malloc` or `realloc` in C.
- For consistency, consider passing `&size` to `init`, and set it to `1` there.

Comment: Thank you for incredibly fast answer. I've fixed the realloc() as you said but still can't use the index notation. I need it because in next step I want to make function which fills x and y of the array.

Comment: @the_Imp You need to use `.`, not `->` there, because `point[1]` is `MYSTRUCT` itself, not a pointer to `MYSTRUCT`.

Comment: Thank you. It works. I try to make other functions and hope it'll works.

Answer (score 0):

You have some type confusion going on... Here:

```
MYSTRUCT *point;
```

you declare `point` to be a pointer to a `MYSTRUCT` structure (or an array of them).

The syntax `point[i]` is equivalent to `*(point + i)` - in other words, it already dereferences the pointer after the addition of the appropriate offset, yielding a `MYSTRUCT` object, not a pointer to one.

The syntax `p->x` is equivalent to `(*p).x`. In other words, it also expects `p` to be a pointer, which it dereferences, and then yields the requested field from the structure.

However, since `point[i]` is no longer a pointer to a `MYSTRUCT`, using `->` on it is wrong. What you are looking for is `point[i].x`. You could alternatively use `(point + i) -> x`, but that's considerably less readable...